# how to save the toggle button state in database and retrive that state

Tags: android

how to save the toggle button state and retrive that state and should access in app.
the following is my edit class in this i want to insert values and update of toggle button state.and was not saving in database and updating.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
     edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.device_text);
     light=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.light);
     alarm=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.alarm);
     db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);
     Intent i = getIntent();
         if(i.hasExtra("Dname"))
             val = i.getStringExtra("Dname");
    slight=light.getText().toString();
    salarm=alarm.getText().toString();
//  edittext.setText(val);
    if(i.hasExtra("Daddress"))
        pos=i.getStringExtra("Daddress");
    db.open();
    db.insertData(pos,val,slight,salarm);
    c = db.getData();
    edittext.setText(val);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    db.open();
    c=db.getData();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        slight=light.getText().toString();
        salarm=alarm.getText().toString();
        if(pos.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
        {
               db.updateData(pos, edittext.getText().toString(),slight,salarm);
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("Dname", edittext.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Daddress",pos);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    } while (c.moveToNext());
          }
     db.close();
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and the following is my database adapter in this i did like this for inserting and update

```
   public long insertData(String uuid,String devicename ,String light,String alarm ) 
   {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(UUID, uuid);
        initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename);
        initialValues.put(LIGHT, light);
        initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
  }

 public long updateData(String uuid,String devicename,String light,String alarm  )
  {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues()
        initialValues.put(DEVICENAME, devicename);
    initialValues.put(LIGHT, light); 
    initialValues.put(ALARM, alarm);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, initialValues,UUID + "= ?",new String[] { uuid});
}
```

Comment: better you try some ToggleButton examples and try your app. i feel this is fully mistaken like light.getText().toString(); http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-simple-togglebutton-example.html

Answer (score 0):

try `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and add values into database as per the toggle button state

//this gives the state of toggle button when it is changed

```
light.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked==true) 
{
//do your operations here
}
else
{
}
```

You can try using share preferences as follows

To save:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if (toggle.isChecked()) 
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

To load:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyle", MODE_PRIVATE);
    toggle.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));
}
```

Comment: how this state i want to get from database when app starts and it should post to toggle button and according to this it should toggle

Comment: can you tell if you want to get state of toggle button and do operations or you want to do operations and then change state of toggle button.

Comment: i should save data in database only because using uuid it should save name,light,alarm values and when app opens it should check and pass those values to next activity.and in that acitvity it should handle those values and perform.

Comment: can you post your error,where exactly you are getting error and wat is the status of database values.is database integrated perfectly?

Comment: no error and i want to set state to toggle button and save to database.when app opens it should check and get those state and pass those to next activity.whatever state is there it should perform that task.

Comment: if u can provide mee email id i can send u coding.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is very small then use `SharedPreferences` instead of `Sqlite`. see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for how to use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: i should save data in database only because using uuid it should save name,light,alarm values and when app opens it should check and pass those values to next activity

Comment: have you debugged your ? is there any exception while inserting or updateing db?

Comment: Error inserting devicename=by alarm=ON uuid=ffffffff-80d2-65d8-80d2-65d800000000 light=ON
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
but i am retriving value when app opens.

Comment: hi,  see this question once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608149/how-to-get-toggle-button-on-when-it-set-text-as-on